# Is blockiness expected for textures with format GL_RGBA8 with unsigned byte & min/mag filter GL_NEAREST?

Tags: opengl-es-3.0

When format GL_RGB5_A1 is used with unsigned_byte texture data (no mipmap), the applied texture is blocky with min/mag filters GL_NEAREST. 
When same code used for format GL_RGBA8, the applied texture is smooth. My assumption was that for RGBA8 too using GL_NEAREST filters the texture image should be blocky as attached. 
OPGNELES 3.0 supports this format and type for textures.
Its a 3D texture of size 256x256x256 applied using glTexImage3D and viewport is set for 640x480.
Texture is generated as below

```
for(k = 0; k < 256; k++) for(j = 0; j < 256; j++) for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    pUBPointer[0] = 255-i;
    pUBPointer[1] = 255-j;
    pUBPointer[2] = 255-k;
    pUBPointer[3] = 0xFF;

    pUBPointer += 4;
}
```

Is it expected?

1. Image for format RGB5_A1
2. Image for format RGBA8

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Works as intended. `nearest` takes only one sample from texture from nearest texel. Difference between RGB8 texels (in one direction) is 1/256 - which is visually almost undistunguishable. However, with RGB5, only 5 bits allocated for each colour, so differense is 1/32.

Comment: Yes, your explanation make sense. Thanks